# node.js web server as a standalone application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver, node-webkit

I have created a node.js-based web server (Javascript file) that serves a web page incorporating Javascript to mobile devices for the control of immersive sound.The web server uses native modules for MIDI and pcap communication. It also uses express for the delivery of the web page. The web server is started from the command line (node M3Dserver.js). I would like it to be a standalone application that can be given to a user to install and run. I have installed node-webkit (nw), and have been able to access the native modules by using nw-gyp. Using express has been a problem. I see that there is node-webkit-express. This appears to be a prototype only tested on Linux. I am concerned that I am heading down a path that is not well trod. Is there a more 'standard' approach to creating a standalone app from the Javascript file of a node.js web server? Would appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given your problems using express I would definitely suggest using the hapi code libary (http://hapijs.com) as the library will have all of them functionality you need but without the complexity of setup it seems you are having trouble with. In the API documents in the site and the walk-through you will find everything you need to get started on a distribution ready app of the sort you are trying to write.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! On a quick scan the hapi library looks good. I will try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have at last got to using hapi, and it does work in a nw.js application and with node. A problem is speed  - in the nw application, a simple page takes a couple of seconds to load, whereas it is immediate with node.  Given below is the route I am using. Any ideas about what might be causing the delay?       server.route({
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/{path*}',
            handler: {
                directory: {
                path: 'public',
                index: true
                }
            }
        });

Comment: Have you got anything installed to run speed tests at the moment? It may be that the particular functions you are trying to use happen to be a lot quicker with node.js and that for your particular usage node is just a better solution. I take it speed is a priority?